# Multiple monitor with different refresh rates

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I currently have three 22" FullHD 60Hz monitors and I'm planning to change my main screen to a 144Hz. Can I configure the system so one monitor is 144Hz and the others are just 60Hz?

Bonus question: I usually do not play in full screen but rather in Borderless Window. Can this cause any problems or make the game run at 60 FPS max?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify different refresh rates for each monitor so long as the monitor and your video card support the refresh rate(s) in question.

Per my own observation in Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, each of my four monitors have their own refresh rate control.  Three of them are running at 60 Hz and the fourth at 59 Hz.

Commentor *stinkyaddy* on the tested.com forum confirms this from his experience as well:

> I have a second monitor that is 30hz and a 60hz with both different rezolutions and it work fine

(*[Source](http://www.tested.com/forums/pc-and-mac/456981-multi-monitor-question-with-different-refresh-rates/)*)